# Simple Blur In OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to mash in a simple blur on an image I'm rendering in OpenGL ES 1.1. I've looked around and found various suggestions for how this might be done, but none that have given good results.

It seems best to render the image to a texture, which I do, as most of the options I've seen online operate on textures rather than anything else. Having done this, one suggestion was the use of the accumulation buffer. I can do stuff like:

```
glAccum(GL_MULT, 0.7);
glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 0.3);
glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0);
```

But the accumulation buffer doesn't seem to be available. Everything I've read suggests it should be in GLES1.1, but no dice.

**Can anyone tell me if the accumulation buffer is in OGLES1.1?**

**Furthermore, does anyone have any better suggestions/improvements on a blur using the Accum buffer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accumulation buffer is not part of OpenGL ES 1.1, you need to do other things to do a blur, such as using blending.

Comment: :Thanks for answer..It is helpful..can you please tell me how do i achieve Blur effect using blending???